# Negative filter condition in athena not working

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I've been trying to apply negative filter conditions in athena query (using NOT along with LIKE or CONTAINS) but it doesn't give any result at all as expected. Is there any other standard to filter with negative conditions?

Eg:

```
select * from(
    select name, array_agg(distinct(subject)) as subjects 
    from table 
    group by name) alias
where (contains(subjects, 'english') and not contains(subjects, 'math'))
```

This query above is expected to return the records the name and aggregated distinct subject array which contains English and doesn't contain Math. But it doesn't work at all. Am I writing the query incorrectly or Athena just doesn't support NOT negation in where clauses?

Comment: can you update your post with sample data and expected output?

Comment: Why not just filter *subject* directly?

Comment: this search must be case sensitive ? word in query are in lowercase but in text firs letter is big

Comment: You could probably use `HAVING` rather than needing to use a nested query. Also, does it work if you just test one part (eg just looking for `english`)? Which part causes it to 'break'?